# How to secure captured or downloaded media files in react native application

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile-security

I want to secure the media file from other third-party apps like file explorer's in Android and iExplore in Mac

Here currently I am saving documents inside the app container only

I want to make the ios app not visible in third party applications like bellow image
similar for android also.

[image]

Any files (video/audio/pdf/any) that are generated within the context of the application are save in the context of the application-protected storage (access through only app).

Comment: Store then in -the equivalent of- getFilesDir().